# Creating a sharepoint quiz

Tags: sharepoint

I have only basic OOB SharePoint skills. I'm trying to make a quiz using the doc found at http://goo.gl/9djRpx but I believe there are steps missing right at the end after the step of "Add the Quiz Web-Part to your page".  Can someone help me with the missing steps?  I think there needs to be a data view web part added but don't know which one to add or how to configure.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
To learn how to ask questions that work on this site please read [ask], especially  [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In this question your should show what you tried and explain what happens. Please don't use shortened links.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is Custom Quiz WebPart could be from the thirdparty. If you want to follows the  step, make sure to **add custom webpart** into sharepoint site and the site collection (this is should be describe in pre-requisites ).

Or if the thirdparty gives you **wsp** solution, you can upload it into solution (find out in **site actions -> site settings**) and make sure **activate** it. Then open and Activate the feature solution from **Site Collection Features** and then **Manage Site Features** .

After all, you could insert the **custom quiz webpart** and continue follow the document.